# Why do we create instances of classes in for loops?

Tags: objective-c

So I am busy reading an objective-c book by Big Nerd Ranch. I'm on chapter 17 at the moment and managed to complete the required challenge at the end of the chapter. However, I just have two question that I would like to understand.

In the following bit of code - StockHolding is a custom class that has instance variables and the stocks (an array) points to three instances of stockholding with values setting its stock value and cost in dollars.

At first I tried to access the array to get the data from the objects it pointed to - but it seems that was not going to work as the array doesn't know what data its objects contain - just where they are in memory, right?

What I want to know is why was it necessary to create a new instance of stockholding (holdings) in this for loop to access those variables? 
How does the new instance of stockholding know what the values of my stocks are?

```
    for (StockHolding *holdings in stocks){

        NSLog (@ "%@ has %d shares. Cost: $%.2f. Stock value: $%.2f", [holdings stockName],[holdings numberOfShares], [holdings costInDollars], [holdings valueInDollars]);
    }
```

I'm going to try have a guess here to see if maybe I understand it a little better?

We create an instance of our class in the for loop so that we have access to its instance methods and variables - then we use the stocks array to get the variables from those objects in the array?

I may be completely off.. :(

Any advice?

Comment: now new instance is being created here in your for loop

Comment: You misunderstand. No new instances are created in the loop. You simple create a variable that points to each existing object in the array.

Answer (score 1):

`stocks` is an array having the objects of type `StockHolding`

So in order to access all values in the array and print the values.You need to get all the  StockHolding instance inside the array we use  `for ...in` method

**note** Here new instance is not created just new reference is made to the memory that is in the array so that you can access it and use it

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no new instances are created in the for loop at all. Since Objective-C objects are always represented as pointers, one variable `!=` one instance. The `holdings` local variable inside the loop is assigned the pointer to the element of the array which is currently being enumerated upon each iteration. It's just a "reference" to an already existing object.

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating new instances. You're iterating through existing instances.

Presumably in [CODE] you have created the objects and added them to the `NSArray`. The for loop just gives them to you one at a time. You name it `holdings`, do something with it, then grab the next.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C objects are typeless. Any message can be sent to any object. Code like `[holdings stockName]` means "send the message 'stockName' to the object 'holdings'". So the Objective-C runtime will inspect the object to see whether it implements that message. If so then it'll pass execution into the implementation.

The type of your object makes no difference to how processing will occur at runtime.

An `NSArray` stores anything that conforms to the `NSObject` protocol. So it can hold any old mix of objects. The same goes for the other collections.

Although you could write all your code without mentioning a single object type, you usually don't because if you say which type of objects you're dealing with then the compiler can perform some sanity checks. That makes you less likely to write broken code.

So the code:

```
for (StockHolding *holdings in stocks)
```

just means "let me do something to every object in the collection `stocks` and don't give me any compiler warnings when I treat them like instances of `StockHolding`". They may actually be other classes. If they're other classes that implement `stockName`, `numberOfShares` and the rest then your code will work perfectly.

So, for example:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfStrings = [NSMutableArray array];

[arrayOfStrings addObject:@"34.3"];
[arrayOfStrings addObject:@"19.8"];

float total;
for(NSNumber *number in arrayOfStrings)
{
    total += [number floatValue];
}
```

Will compile and work perfectly — not because the strings are actually converted to numbers but because both classes implement `floatValue` to return a `float`. So each `NSNumber *number` is actually an `NSString`, and if you tried to call, say, `isEqualToNumber:` on any of them you'd raise an exception because that isn't implemented by strings. But telling the compiler you're going to act as if they're numbers means you don't get a warning for using `floatValue` and when the runtime spots that the object implements `floatValue` execution continues as usual.

Answer (score 0):

**The for..in loop is used for fast enumeration.**

This

```
for (StockHolding *holdings in stocks)
{

}
```

won't create any new object, it takes one object from array and cast it to the specified type and assign it to the specified variable.

**Means:**

1. Takes the object from the array . Equivalent to `[stocks objectAtIndex:index];`
2. Assign it to the specified object. Equivalent to `StockHolding *holdings = [stocks objectAtIndex:index];`

Note that *Only the reference is used (assignment) there is no object is allocated.*